# Raspberry pi 3 Model B+ : ACT light not blinking

Tags: pi-3

While i am working on pc my raspberry pi working correctly , but suddenly it's display gone. And rebooting it again it not blink ACT light at least 1 time. Means it not blink any time.  Also , i have checked my sd card to another raspberry pi and it boot os properly. but in my sd card slot it is not booting.
So, what's the problem? Is it sd card slot corrupted? or anything else. Please help me.

Comment: if you tried only what you said that you tried, then you missed the most obvious thing ... go back and recheck everything

Comment: What do you mean by "gone"? Stolen?

Comment: What display? Bare Raspberry Pi does not have a display.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the display is out due to overheating of the pi device (happened to me many times when having very long-running hours). You shall let it cool down and try again.

Also, you shall power the pi device from the electric power source and not the PC because sometimes electric fluctuation of PC's power will cause damage to the device and/or USB port of PC.

Thanks